# SQL which patients had appointments with more than 1 doctor (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table appointments(id,patientID,doctorID)
I want to check which patients had appointments with more than 1 doctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and the `HAVING` clause to check if a patient has more than one distinct doctor.

```
select patientId
from appointments
group by patientId
having count(distinct doctorId) > 1;
```